# Magento backend_model - do I need to specify for each config field?

Tags: magento

If I want to do something extra when a particular configuration field for my custom module is saved  (over and above saving to the Magento core config table), I can just specify a backend_model for that field in my system.xml, and have that backend model class extend Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data, override _afterSave, and put my extra stuff in that method.

But what if I have several fields I want to do this for. I don't want the behaviour to be to save field1 and call my afterSave for that field, save field2 and call my afterSave for that field, etc. I'd rather that all the fields were saved to the Magento core config table, and then I do my extra stuff.

Is that possible? I thought I might be able to achieve that using event/observer. So in my config.xml, <adminhtml> section, I added an observer as follows:

```
<events>
    <admin_system_config_changed_mysection>
        <observers>
            <mypfx_admin_system_config_changed_mysection>
                <class>mymodule/adminhtml_system_config_backend_configSaveObserver</class>
                <method>myConfigSaved</method
            </mypfx_admin_system_config_changed_mysection>
        </observers>
    </admin_system_config_changed_mysection>    
</events>
```

but my observer method is not called when the config is saved. Maybe I have the wrong event name? The "mysection" bit on the end of the event name I was guessing had to match the section from system.xml:

```
<sections>    
    <mysection translate="label" module="mymodule">
        ...
        <groups>
            ...
        </groups>
    </mysection>
</sections>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event you're trying to listen for doesn't exist.  Here's what you want to do, and some tips for picking the right event in the future.

First, every event is fired in Magento by the `Mage::dispatchEvent` method.  Search the core code for these calls and you'll always know the name of the event you want to listen for.

```
$ ack 'admin_system_config_changed_'
Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php
136:            Mage::dispatchEvent("admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section}",
```

From the above, you can see the name of the event vs. what you thought it was

```
admin_system_config_changed_section_{$section}
admin_system_config_changed_mysection
```

So, it looks like you're missing the `section` before your own section name.

Second, while working on a development box, the **best** way to find the event you're looking for is to log things at the source.  Temporarily add some debugging code to the `dispatchEvent` function.

```
#File: app/Mage.php
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{   
    //either one of the lines below should do it.  One uses Magento's
    //built in logging, the other uses something more crude 
    #Mage::Log($name);
    #file_put_contents('/tmp/test.log',"$name\n",FILE_APPEND);    

    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    #$result = self::registry('events')->dispatch($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

This will dump a huge list of event names out to your log. I typically use OS X's `Console.app` to view the log file during the request, copy the lines out, sort and remove duplicates, and then end up with a list like this

```
admin_system_config_changed_section_commercebug
admin_user_load_after
admin_user_load_before
adminhtml_block_html_before
adminhtml_controller_action_predispatch_start
application_clean_cache
controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after
controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_before
controller_action_layout_generate_xml_before
controller_action_layout_load_before
controller_action_layout_render_before
controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_system_config_edit
controller_action_postdispatch
controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml
controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_config_edit
controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_config_save
controller_action_predispatch
controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml
controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_system_config_edit
controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_system_config_save
controller_front_init_before
controller_front_init_routers
controller_front_send_response_after
controller_front_send_response_before
core_abstract_load_after
core_abstract_load_before
core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after
core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before
core_block_abstract_to_html_after
core_block_abstract_to_html_before
core_collection_abstract_load_after
core_collection_abstract_load_before
core_config_data_load_after
core_config_data_save_after
core_config_data_save_before
core_config_data_save_commit_after
core_layout_block_create_after
core_locale_set_locale
core_session_abstract_add_message
core_session_abstract_clear_messages
http_response_send_before
model_load_after
model_load_before
model_save_after
model_save_before
model_save_commit_after
resource_get_tablename
store_load_after
store_load_before
```

You still need to use some intelligence guessing to figure out which event you want, but they're named intuitively enough that you can usually find what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you. I have a file that is the result of my grep for dispatchEvent, but I just mistyped the event name, missing out "section". Thanks for spotting that and sorry for being an idiot! That said, I made the change and still didn't get my observer method called - so I'll give your dispatchEvent debug suggestion a go to ensure the event is being fired with the name I expect. It's amazing that the events aren't documented (the doc the dbcn mentions is very poor). Difficult to find all events that can be fired by using grep as often the event name is not a string literal.

Comment: adding "section" to the event name worked fine. I had stupidly changed the xml placeholder in config.xml rather than the event name. I think I should just go home now!

Answer (score -2):

You need to tie your observer method to a specific Magento event (you can add your own, but need to find when you want it to be fired and add your own dispatchEvent call). If Magento has an event built in, use that event name in the config.

There's a pdf of the built in event lists on the web - google for it & you'll find it.