# Magento - module with system config, how do I do something on save?

Tags: magento

I have a simple module created with the Magento Module Creator with a couple of settings in admin->system->config.

When I go to these settings and choose the enable/disable option, the settings get saved - which is great - however, I want to run my own code after that, i.e. on the save action, once the data has been saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although it isnt a good idea but you can achieve it by observers:

```
<controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_mymodule_mycontroller_myaction>
```

replace the my-s with module_controller_action, and most likely you want to put it in this event:

```
<controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_config_save>
```

in your config xml as follows:

```
<controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_config_save>
    <observers><myobserver>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>mymodule/observer</class>
        <method>mymethod</method> 
    </myobserver></observers>
</controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_system_config_save>
```

and in mymodule, as in your module have a class observer in mymodule/Model/Observer.php

and declare the observer as

```
class modules_mymodule_observer {
     public function myfunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
         //do your stuffs
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful help. I think you pointed me in the right direction, however, I also took inspiration from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822459/magento-backend-model-do-i-need-to-specify-for-each-config-field and got there in the end. Observers are a good idea so long as you get the right one - do see linked article and thanks for your speedy help.

Comment: This article on validating the system config values shows how you can setup a backend model to have stuff happen before and after a save http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_config_validation

Answer (score 6):

In your `etc/system.xml` add a [backend model](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/xml_structure_for_admin_configurations#backend_model) descended from `Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data` and use it's `_afterSave()` method to run your code.